# how to call two functions from a menu item?

Tags: drupal-6

I have a menu item and I want to call two functions on it. Here is my code.

`$items['admin/proformative/reports'] = array(

    'title' => 'report',

    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',

    'page arguments' => array('test_reports'),

    'access callback' => TRUE,

    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,

  );`


It works fine but as in page_arguments i have call one function. And Now i want to call two functions. I change the above code as following but did not work.

`$items['admin/proformative/reports'] = array(

    'title' => 'report',

    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',

    'page arguments' => array('test_vbo', 'test_reports'),

    'access callback' => TRUE,

    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,

  );`


But it only executes the test_vbo function and i want both to execute.

What should i need to achieve the above technique.

Answer (score 1):

Your page callback is drupal_get_form, which renders the form that is returned from the page argument, which is the test_vbo function.  If you want to render multiple forms, you can wrap the drupal_get_form calls in single function and use that as the page callback:

```
 $items['admin/proformative/reports'] = array(
    'title' => 'report',
    'page callback' => 'test_my_function',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
 );

function test_my_function() {
   return drupal_get_form('test_vbo') . drupal_get_form('test_reports');
}
```